# How do you use variable arguments to wrap a certain function taking an Object[]

Tags: java

I have a method which takes key and its associated parameters in the following format.

```
public String foo(String key, Object[] parameters) {..}
```

I would prefer to pass the parameters using a variable argument format. How should I do that?

I tried `public String foo(String key, Object... parameters) {..}` - But this seems to collide with the method definition given above.

Should I do something like the following and wrap this into the Object[] method?

```
public String foo(String key, Object a) {..}
public String foo(String key, Object a, Object b) {..}    
public String foo(String key, Object a, Object b, Object c) {..}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the definition of the existing function to

```
public String foo(String key, Object... parameters) {..}
```

The variadic method mechanism in Java is syntactic sugar for creating an array at the call site and passing it in.  So this method should be compatible with existing source code *and* compiled classes.

From [the Java documentation on varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array *or* as a sequence of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Give the method a different name:

```
public String bar(String key, Object... a) {
    return foo(key, a);
}
```

The name should be close to the original one, probably specifying the reason why it exists (but this can be documented as well). I can't be more specific with "foo" :)

This is of course needed *if you can't change the existing method signature*, for example inheriting from a 3rd party class. If you can change it - change it. Old invocations will still work.

Answer (score 2):

`public String foo(String key, Object[] parameters)` and `public String foo(String key, Object... parameters)` are the same methods, their ("class file") signatures are equivalent.

If you have a method like

```
public String foo(String key, Object... parameters) {}
```

the follwing calls are allowed:

```
foo("1", obj1);
foo("2", obj1, obj2);
foo("3", new Object[]{obj1, obj2, obj3});
```

Comment: *"...are the same methods, their signatures are equivalent"* Er, really? So I can call `public String foo(String key, Object[] parameters`) with five arguments: `foo("hi", "does", "this", "really", "work");`? Seems unlikely. **Edit**: Tested. Nope, you can't. You can't have both, but their signatures are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - yes and no... on *byte code level*, the signatures are the same - the compiler just adds some glue to create an `Object[]` from the parameters and passes that one to the method. That's what I *wanted* to say.

Answer (score 1):

`public String foo(String key, Object[] parameters) {..}` and

`public String foo(String key, Object... parameters) {..}` are equal

Comment: not quite. The eclipse compiler does not like invoking a non-varargs method with varargs.